# Can istio manage applications which aren't deployed with kubernetes or consul systems?

Tags: istio

I'd like to use istio in an environment which hasn't adapted to kubernetes or consul yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to make this from out the box without Kubernetes or consul. There are only two options in [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/): Kubernetes or Nomad & Consul. It is required storage so you need to use Kubernetes or Nomad & Consul to place all Istio services. However, you can take the code of [Istio](https://github.com/istio/istio) and adapt it to your purpose. Istio is an open source product and it allows you any modifications.